# how to solve the graph with cycles

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I am trying to find a solution for the next problem with help of Java. I have a graph, this is a good example of how it could look:

[image]

There is its notation:

[{**A** = {C = 0.7}, {D = 0.3}}, 
 {**C** = {out = 0.2}, {F = 0.8}}, 
 {**D** = {C = 0.1}, {F = 0.2}, {G = 0.3}, {E = 0.4}},
 {**S** = {A = 0.4},{B = 0.6}},
 {**E** = {G = 0.3},{out = 0.7}},
 {**G** = {B = 0.2}{out = 0.8}},
 ...

**S** - is a start node (S = 1), **out** - is a way out of the graph.

I want to trace the graph and know how much percentage each node has. 
In instance, **A** = 0.4*S (S = 1), **C** = 0.7A + 0.1D , **D** = 0.3A + 0.7B

I thought it is possible to do it with recursion(DFS for directed graphs, in particular Tarjan's alg.), but while there are cycles I do not think it helps. Another solution is to solve a system of linear equations.
I do not know what is better that would work, and maybe there are some solutions exist for this kind of tasks.
This example is just an example, but I should consider that I have like appr. 2000 nodes (and who know how many cycles).

How would you do it?

Comment: Why BFS instead of DFS? DFS will probably find the way out sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving linear equations seems to be a very good approach.

You can try to use [Gaussian Elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination). I am pretty sure you can just find already written Java code to do it for you, on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Note: for cyclic graphs, solving one system of linear equations **does not give you the probabilities**. It gives you the expected multiplicity.

Okay, the problem is given a graph *G*, for each node to compute the probability with which that node is visited. Here's an exact algorithm.

1. Compute the strongly connected components (SCCs) of the graph.
2. For each SCC *C*, for each possible starting node *v* in *C*, compute via solving systems of linear equations (a) the distribution of arcs leaving *C* and (b) the probability with which each node in *C* is visited. The best way I know to achieve (b) is to consider a product graph whose nodes are pairs. The first element of the pair is a node in *C*. The second element is a subset of nodes in *C* that have been visited. Arcs are inherited from *C*. Solve some linear equations to find out the distribution of last nodes in this new graph.
3. Prepare a new graph *H* on the vertices of *G* with arcs from *v* to *w* when *v* and *w* are in different components of *G* and there's a path from *v* to *w*. The probability of this arc is as determined in Step 2(a).
4. Solve the acyclic problem on *H*.
5. For each node, compute the weighted sum of probabilities from Step 2(b).

This algorithm is basically linear in the size of the graph but *exponential* in the size of the SCCs. I'm not sure what your cycles look like.

Comment: I think the probability with which each node is visited.

Comment: There is no any pattern of cycles in such a graph. I've read your solution and it seams complicated but worth trying. And as I see maybe it's better to omit cycles.